# Adding SSL to CometD

Tags: node.js, ssl, ssl-certificate, cometd, genesys

I am using CometD library for nodejs on server side using the https://www.npmjs.com/package/cometd-nodejs-client. The server (Genesys) that I am trying to connect uses SSL, due to SSL cert I am getting SSL error when connecting to the server using CometD. My question is that is there a way to pass the ca cert to CometD library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cometd)?

Comment: What error do you get? Genesys should have their certificates signed properly, no?

Comment: I am getting "SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain" when connecting to Genesys.

Answer (score 1):

The `XMLHttpRequest` provided by the CometD library exposes a `_config()` function that returns a configuration object that is passed to Node's `http.request(...)`, allowing you to configure TLS if so you need.

You can refer to this test case:

https://github.com/cometd/cometd-nodejs-client/blob/1.3.0/test/https.js#L53

Answer (score 0):

I am also seeing a similar issue when using CometD and CometD Client packages to connect to Genesys.

I have a nodejs server that adds all the `/meta/handshake, /meta/connect, /meta/disconnect`... listeners. When I try to trigger the `/meta/handshake` I seeing `SSL self signed certificate in certificate chain` error. As a solution, I tried to install the ssl certificates on my server and tried to connect to Genesys but I still see the same self signed certificate error.

Is there a way to configure the listeners with `rejectUnauthorized: false`?

Comment: @sbordet could you please let me know if this is possible?